# Will leveldb method put update a value?

Tags: api, documentation, leveldb

Will the method `put` update a value or is it necessary to first `delete` it and then `put` the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will update value (delete is not required). Do you have any problem with it?

Comment: @joelle-feeney no I just got confused by my data. Now everything works.